# Drawing without replacement. Problem formally specifying the probability space.

Tags: probability

An urn contains  $4$ blue and $4$ red marbles. At first a marble is drawn (without looking) and removed from the urn. Then, a marble is drawn from the urn, its color recorded and put back in the bag. This process is repeated $1000$ times.

1. Stochastically model this experiment with an appropriate probability space. Give a precise mathematical description of the random variable $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,1000$ that takes the value $1$ only if the $i$-th drawn marble out of the $1000$ is blue, $0$ else.

---

I am really having trouble specifying the [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$. Here is my attempt:

The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes. Basically I can only draw a blue or a red marble so I was thinking:

$$\Omega=\{R,B\} \,\,\,\,\text{or}\,\,\,\, \Omega=\{1,0\}$$

Assuming that $1$ corresponds to blue and $0$ corresponds to red.  The sample space in this example would be the set of all possible $n$-tuples of length $1000$.

$$\mathcal F:=\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{1000}), a_j\in \Omega \}$$

I am not really sure what to write for $P$. Is this supposed to be some sort of rule for a probability? I also tried writing an expression for the random variable $X_i$ with the indicator function:

$$X_i=\sum_{n=1}^{1000} \mathbf{1}_{a_i=1}$$

But it's not really specific. I wanted to write down something that would take a string from the event space $\mathcal F$ and return $1$ if the $i$-the component is $1$ but I can't seem to write it down properly.

Comment: Initially you draw a marble which is red or blue.  Then you do $1000$ more draws.  So you could have $\Omega=\{\text{red}, \text{blue}\}^{1001}$ and $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$ though its elements are not equally likely

Comment: @Henry I always get so confused by this. I always thought $\Omega$ is the set of possible outcomes of a single trial. You are saying  $\Omega$ is set of possible outcomes of the scenario "$\text{I draw marble and remove it without looking and then draw a marble 1000 times}$". I thought that's the event space. What's the difference between the event space and the sample space then?

Comment: The event space is really $\mathcal F$, a sigma-algebra whose elements are subsets of the sample space $\Omega$ which has all the possible outcomes

Comment: @Henry Is the notation $\Omega=\{{\text{red},\text{blue}}\}^{1001}$ short for all the strings $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n), a_i \in \{{\text{red},\text{blue}}\}, i=1,\dots,1001$? Would $\mathcal F$ also include events such as $(\text{red},\text{blue},\text{red})$ which would only correspond to drawing three times?

Comment: Yes and yes.  More importantly it includes the event that the initial draw was red and the $486$th was blue with probability $\frac{3}{14}$ as well as the event that the the $486$th was blue with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How did you get the probabilities in your example though? I tried to calculate it $$P(a_{486}=\text{blue} \vert a_1=\text{red})=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{7}=\frac{2}{7}$$. The second one makes sense: $$P(a_{486} \lvert \text{first draw unknonwn} )=\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{7}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{7}=\frac{7}{14}=\frac{1}{2}$$. Is there some sort of mathematically precise way to describe these events. For example the events "The first $6$ marbles drawn are red" or"503 out of $1000$ are red". How would I write those mathematically?

Comment: @Henry Also I have a follow up question regarding probabilities. Assume The event $A$ is the event that a blue marble was removed, $B$ the event that $497$ marbles out of the $1000$ draws were red. Would the event $P(A \vert B)$ not be just $\frac{1}{2}$ because what I draw first is not influenced given that i drew $497$ red marbles after right? I can also open this in another question if this is getting too long for the comments.

Comment: Since B has more blue draws than red, you might reasonably guess that the initial draw was more likely to have been red than blue.  And if you do the calculations with $497$ red and $503$ blue then you would find $P(A \mid B) \approx 0.151$.  The timing of the draws is not the point here - it is about using the information you know to find out what is more likely about what you do not know.